# React JS is not changing state after event inside FileReader

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been trying to assign as a state the contents of a .txt file uploaded locally via an input tag. I used File Reader, however although the content of the files is printed, the state is not changed according to React dev tools.

Here's the code:

```
handleFile = (file) => {
var fileReader = new FileReader()
fileReader.readAsText(file)
fileReader.onloadend = function (e) {
  var content = e.target.result
  console.log(content)
  this.setState={
    text: content
  }

}
```

The function handleFile is being called here:

```
<input type="file" accept='.txt' className="custom-file-input" id="customFile"
onChange={e => this.handleFile(e.target.files[0])} />
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: tip: `content = await file.text()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setState is a method, so to use it you should type something like:

```
this.setState({key:value})
```

but it wouldn't work, couse "this" in your code is link to fileReader - and you need React. Try to use arrow function to throw correct "this":

```
fileReader.onloadend = (e)=> {
var content = e.target.result
console.log(content)
this.setState({
  text: content
})
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, didn't notice the error while calling setState, also thanks for explaining the context of this!

Answer (score 0):

try `this.setState({ text: content })` without the = 
also use arrow function because this is not recognized in regular functions